# Disable focus button

Tags: c#

I have a simple question.
In my form a lot of buttons. About 40. I want to disable focus on the buttons with arrows. TabIndex prohibits the use of tab, but not the arrow. All buttons has a TabIndex = 0 but I still can use arrows.

Comment: Pretty unclear why you want to make it so difficult for the user to operate your UI.  Override ProcessCmdKey() and return *true* if you see a cursor key.

Comment: Disable the focus on buttons means you want to switch the focus from one button to another when arrows are pressed right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Sudhakar

Comment: @MaximDroy: see my edited answer if it helps you, also let me know how would you want to switch the focus from one button to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you custom button and set style selectable=false

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
  public CustomButton()
  {
     this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Override the `ProcessCmdKey()` to handle the Cursor Keys

**Sample Code:**

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Up )
            {
               button1.Focus();
               return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Note: if you can explain your problem more clearly we can help you better.

Comment: Please try code you post yourself first.  Shouldn't take more than a minute or two to discover that this doesn't work at all.  KeyPreview is a VB6 compatibility property, meant to implement shortcut keystrokes in that language.  The cursor keys are never shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable Inputs . i have made changes as per your comment.Thanks a lot.